# How much space between a displayed formula and the associated qualifier?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

A very common way to indicate a universally qualified statement in a math display is exemplified by the display

> *x*<sup>2</sup> ≥ 0                                                                (*x* ∈ **R**)

where the "(*x* ∈ **R**)" parenthesized expression is pushed toward the right.

In LaTeX, one can of course mimic this formatting with something like:

```
x^2 \geq 0 \qquad\qquad\qquad (x \in \mathbb{R})
```

With the default setting of centered (*non*-flushleft) formulas, is there some good way to do the horizontal spacing of such math displays in a consistent way throughout a document?

I would *not* want the parenthesized expression to be pushed all the way to the right margin, because that would interfere with normal equation numbering or tagging.

Comment: `\qquad` is usually sufficient

Comment: Another solution is to use the align environment where every second & corresponds to a big gap.

Comment: Using the `align` environment may be problematic given that some math displays may be using `alignat`, and many will already use subsidiary `aligned` or `alignedat` environments.

Answer (score 4):

Either `\quad` or `\qquad` should be sufficient. Using either two or three consecutive `\qquad` instructions seems excessive.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts} % for "\mathbb" macro
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for "gather*" environment
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
x^2 \geq 0 \quad (x\in\mathbb{R})\\[3ex]
x^2 \geq 0 \qquad (x\in\mathbb{R})\\[3ex]
x^2 \geq 0 \qquad\qquad (x\in\mathbb{R})\\[3ex]
x^2 \geq 0 \qquad\qquad\qquad (x\in\mathbb{R})
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use `\mathrlap` from `mathtools`, as follows. (The extra code is just to frame the text body area, as in https://ipfs-sec.stackexchange.cloudflare-ipfs.com/tex/A/question/122683.html.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts} % for "\mathbb" macro
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\qual}[1]{\mathrlap{\qquad#1}}
\newcommand{\qqual}[1]{\mathrlap{\qquad\qquad#1}}
\newcommand{\qqqual}[1]{\mathrlap{\qquad\qquad\qquad#1}}

% Just to frame text body...
\usepackage{background}% to show text body area
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{background}
\newlength{\xinnersep}
\setlength{\xinnersep}{0.05cm}
\newlength{\yinnersep}
\setlength{\yinnersep}{0.05cm}
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
contents={%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[gray,line width=1.5pt,] ([xshift=-\xinnersep,yshift=\yinnersep]current page text area.north west) --
                                             ([xshift=\xinnersep,yshift=\yinnersep]current page text area.north east) -- 
                                             ([xshift=\xinnersep,yshift=-\yinnersep]current page text area.south east) -- 
                                             ([xshift=-\xinnersep,yshift=-\yinnersep]current page text area.south west) -- cycle;
 \end{tikzpicture}%
}}

\begin{document}

New way, with \verb!\qual!, etc:
\begin{gather*}
x^2 \geq 0 \qual{ (x\in\mathbb{R}) }\\[3ex]
x^2 \geq 0 \qqual{ (x\in\mathbb{R}) }\\[3ex]
x^2 \geq 0 \qqqual{ (x\in\mathbb{R}) }
\end{gather*}

Old way, with \verb!\qquad!:
\begin{gather*}
x^2 \geq 0 \qquad (x\in\mathbb{R})\\[3ex]
x^2 \geq 0 \qquad\qquad (x\in\mathbb{R})\\[3ex]
x^2 \geq 0 \qquad\qquad\qquad (x\in\mathbb{R})
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Using \mathrlap to space qualifiers in math display]